# Checking if the first character of a string is a number gives an error that charat is not a valid method

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a method that validates a field against 3 regex expressions and returns an error based on which expression failed.

```
function mfpValidateValue()
{
    var pCtrl = window.document.forms[0].txtValue;

    var pStrValue  =  mTrim(pCtrl.value);
    if (pStrValue == '')
        return true;

    var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}.{0,3}$"); // First 9 are numeric followed by up to any 3 characters
    var regexLetter1 = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}$"); //Up to the first 3 are alpha, then there are exactly 6 numbers
    var regexLetter2 = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{9}$"); //Up to the first 3 are alpha, then there are exactly 9 numbers
    var error = "";

    // If any of the RegEx fails, set base error message
    if (!regexNum.test(pStrValue) || !regexLetter1.test(pStrValue) || !regexLetter2.test(pStrValue))
        error = "Please enter a valid Value.";

    // Set more specific error message. 
    if (!isNaN(pStrValue.charat(0)))
        error += " If the first character of Value is a digit, then the first nine characters must be digits.";
    else
        error += " If the first character of Value is a letter, up to the first three characters must be letters proceeded by 6 or 9 digits.";

    return (error == "");
}
```

I get the following error message on this line:

```
    if (!isNaN(pStrValue.charat(0)))
```

> Object doesn't support property or method 'charat'

And the value in `pStrValue` is:

> "12345678"

Is JavaScript using the term "object" ambiguously here to refer to my particular variable, or does it actually think `pStrValue` is an object and not a string?

Comment: `charAt`, not `charat`. Javascript is case-sensitive

Comment: ....Well that's horribly embarassing. If you want to post that as the answer I'll select it. VS2008's javascript intellisense isn't very good, and I'm worse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a minor mistake. `charat()` is not a function, but `charAt()` is.

Your code should be

```
 if (!isNaN(pStrValue.charAt(0)))
```

Here is the function

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp

Answer (score 1):

You check this:

*if not is Not a Number*

The new ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) has a new method:

> Number.isInteger(value)

Mozilla Developer Network describes:

> If the target value is an integer, return true, otherwise return false. If the value is NaN or infinite, return false.

See full information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

A proper alternative is:

```
if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(pStrValue.charAt(0))))
```

Comment: While I suppose I could make the logic easier to read and simply do `if (isnan...) //second error message first`, it wasn't a logic mistake to do it as I had written. I'll look into that other method, but our web app has to support browsers as old as IE7 so I don't know if that'd be an issue?

Comment: Ok, check the MDN link, but I don't think so. Why do you have to support IE7? I  support only from IE9 since 2011 and never problems :-)

Comment: Work with the medical field. Lots of those companies aren't keep on upgrading technology... ever :(

Comment: `if (Number.isInteger(pStrValue.charAt(0)))` won't work. It'll return `false` even if `pStrValue.charAt(0)` is numeric. For `Number.isInteger()` to return `true` it needs to be passed an integer number. So in this case, you'd need to use `parseInt()` to get it to work.